# Ask Finder to open a specified folder with apple script

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

I use Dragon dictate to automate many things.  I would like to open a particular folder in finder.  for example when  I say "open downloads" it executes the following shell script:
`open /Volumes/3TB\ Storage/Downloads/`

however this always opens the folder in a new window.  I would like the script to open the folder in a new tab if a finder window already exists.  If no finder window exists then it should open the  folder in a new window.

after surfing the net for three  hours  and trying multiple solutions I cannot get this to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us some of the approaches you tried.  That way, we can avoid wasting time barking up wrong trees.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: The below Code work for me.  I was trying the same thing before and the Dragon dictate window and getting random errors.  When I typed it into the AppleScript  editor  it worked well and then I copied and pasted it out of there.               <br/>                                                                  /n`set path1 to ("/Volumes/3TB Storage/Downloads") as POSIX file
tell application "Finder"
 if window 1 exists then
  activate
  tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
  set target of front window to path1
 else
  open path1
 end if
 
end tell`

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You really should take the time and read, at a minimum, the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my last post was  edited very poorly. Here is the answer.

```
    set path1 to ("/Volumes/3TB Storage/Downloads") as POSIX file 
    tell application "Finder" 
    if window 1 exists then 
        activate 
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using 
        command down 
        set target of front window to path1 
    else 
        open path1 
    end if 
    end tell
```